# PHP : Can not call object method from a page which included by another method of my class

Tags: php, oop

I have just created a class to control my php application, and I have one big problem ( I use 2 days for thinking and searching about it but can't find any solutions). My class contains a method named `register()`, which load scripts into pages. My class is:

```
class Apps
{
  protected $_remember; // remember something

  public function register($appName)
  {
     include "$appName.php"; //include this php script into other pages
  }

  public function set($value)
  {
     $this->_remember = $value; // try to save something
  }

  public function watch()
  {
     return $this->_remember; // return what I saved
  }
}
```

And in `time.php` file

```
$time = 'haha';

$apps->set($time);
```

As the title of my question , when I purely include `time.php` into `main.php`, I **can** use `$apps->set($time)` (`$apps` has been defined in `main.php`). Like this `main.php`:

```
$apps = new Apps();// create Apps object

include "time.php";

echo $apps->watch(); // **this successfully outputs 'haha'**
```

But when I call method `register()` from Apps class to include `time.php` , I got errors `undefined variable $apps` and `call set method from none object` for `time.php` (sounds like it doesn't accept `$apps` inside `time.php` to me) . My `main.php` is:

```
$apps = new Apps();// create Apps object

$apps->register('time'); // this simply include time.php into page and it has
                      //included but time.php doesn't accept $apps from main.php

echo $apps->watch(); // **this outputs errors as I said**
```

By the way , I'm not good at writing . So if you don't understand anything just ask me. I appreciate any replies. :D

Comment: Read about variable scope in PHP. The scope of the included file starts and ends within the function `register`. To verify this, use a `var_dump($this);` in the to be included PHP file and you will see what scope I'm talking about :)

Comment: This is very helpful . I can do it now . Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your second code snippet to work, replace the content of `time.php` with:

```
$time = 'haha';

$this->set($time); // instead of $apps->set($time);
```

since this code is `include`d by an instance method of the `Apps` class, it will have access to the instance itself, `$this`.